# Bandwidth Consumption on a deeper level

Tags: c++, c

I'm using an Ubuntu OS and I know one can get an average usage of bandwidth of a PC by reading the file /proc/net/dev file. However, suppose I'm transmitting files to two nodes at the same time (Total transmitting BW: 100 Mpbs). Can anyone suggest me a good idea how to get/store the information of 'Transmitting BW to Node X/Y" (X: 50 Mbps/ Y: 50 Mbps). Suggestions in C/C++ or python are highly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 0):

The kernel doesn't ordinarily care beyond what the next hop for a packet is and what interface to drop it on to get it there.  To make it care, you need some of linux's high-end routing capabilities.  Try this:

```
DEV=`ip route|sed -nr 's/^default.* dev ([^ ]*).*/\1/p'`
/sbin/tc qdisc del dev $DEV root >/dev/null 2>&1
TQ="/sbin/tc qdisc add dev $DEV"
TC="/sbin/tc class add dev $DEV"
TF="/sbin/tc filter add dev $DEV"
$TQ root handle 1: htb default 0 
$TC parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbps # interesting destination 1
$TC parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 100mbps # ...
$TF parent 1: protocol ip u32 match ip dst 123.231.132.213 classid 1:1
$TF parent 1: protocol ip u32 match ip dst 1.2.3.4 classid 1:2
```

and then you can get stats with `tc -s class show dev $DEV`.  I don't know an easier way to do this, sorry.

Comment: @jthill...The script which you pasted...sorry to ask such an elementary question...should I copy paste the script or what? :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `jnettop` utility, either to get the information you need directly, or to find the appropriate techniques in its source code.